# Comparing frequencies or proportions between two groups to find differences

Tags: machine-learning, ranking, anomaly-detection

Suppose I have two groups of users, A and B. In case it is relevant, B is much smaller than A.

I have a feature of products purchased across two groups. I want to find items whose popularity is different between the groups and ultimately classify group membership based off this for unlabelled data.

**Example**: Suppose the feature is “product”. My data might look like:

Product, Percentage Group A, Percentage Group B,

Apple, 90%, 80%

Banana 50%, 49%

Chicken 0%, 90%

Lamb   1%, 60%

Kale 50%, 20%

… more stuff

So 90% of people in group A purchased an apple. Nobody in group A purchased chicken. (I also have the raw counts if that is useful).

**Data notes:**

- The lists are **very** long, Group A may buy products that do not appear in Group B and vice versa, like chicken above.
- In the real use case the product names may not carry a semantic meaning.
- There are many products which only one user has purchased. So far I am just dropping items which only a “few” users have purchased.

**Goal:**
I am trying to find differences in the purchases between the two groups and any related insights, ultimately to determine likely group membership based on products purchased. For example above we could observe that chicken is very popular in group B but does not appear in group A. ***What I am particularly interested in is any stand out differences, like chicken in the example above, where if someone purchased chicken I would be much more likely to think they belong to group B instead of group A.***

**What have I tried:**
One thing I have tried is to calculate the difference in ranking between the two groups and look for items where the difference is large.

Domain experts tell me there are practical differences between the groups. Above it might turn out there is a statistically significant difference between the two groups in purchasing bananas, but the difference between 50 and 49 percent is so small, I doubt my stakeholders would be that interested, compared to the insight about the chicken.

Comment: To answer this interesting question, a few more details are needed
( sorry here is not an answer yet, but I lack reputation to just comment your question): is it right that you have the complete purchase data for each individual in group A and B? and are the data just Apple:yes/no or more detailed? how many individuals roughly, and how many items (apples, bananas)? running tests on each category (apple, banana…) separately would create a multiple testing situation. Standard multiple testing corrections (Bonferroni…) assume independence, which is the choice when you do not have complete informa

Comment: [tag:chi-square]? [tag:logistic] regression?

Comment: Hi  @Ute, I  have the complete purchase data for all users, and I also have the quantity of each item they have purchased (and when). I thought it might make the analysis easier to just say have they bought this product, but I do have the complete purchase history. I have thousands of items and say hundred thousand users in group A and several thousand in B.

Comment: Hi @Sycorax. Thanks for your suggestions. Would I use chi-square separately for each product type or across everything at once? If I have hundreds of products with a stat significant difference, is there a “good” way to find the “big” items (something like an effect size)? Would the LR be at the individual user level, predicting group based on purchases? I am thinking out loud here but something like an odds ratio might be useful here for explainability.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of different ways to do this. I think the most straightforward however is logistic regression, given your requirements (you need which items are most important and at the same time make class assignments for future datapoints).

You could fit a logistic regression model to predict whether an individual is a member of group A or of group B, using the number of purchases of each item as features. (I'm assuming you have a wealth of individual-level data here). You can then calculate an odds ratio for each feature (i.e. how much each additional purchase of item X increases the odds of being Group B) and a 95% CI on that odds ratio. This functionality is standard in most software packages you can use to do logistic regression (e.g. in R or in statsmodels or scikit-learn in Python, see this [StackOverflow for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647396/statsmodels-logistic-regression-odds-ratio)). This therefore simultaneously answers the question posed by your end users (which features are most important) and constructs a predictive model you can use on new data.

Since your dataset is imbalanced (significantly more class A than class B datapoints), you'll need to use class weighting. You might also need to use L1 (promotes sparsity) or L2 (promotes small weight values) regularization. L1 regularization can be particularly useful if you want a sparse solution (i.e. want most of the weights to be zero so that only a small subset of the features are used, which I think is what you are after). A regularization technique that may be especially useful for your case is [elastic net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization), which is a combination of L1 and L2 regularization. I would do some experiments (e.g. [5x cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics))) on a small subset of your training data to see if regularization is beneficial and if so what hyperparameter setting you need.

Alternatively, you might want to know which items offer the best differentiation between categories and then use only *those* as inputs to your logistic regression model, in other words, do feature selection before fitting. In this case, you could use a [chi-square test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test) at the level of each item (i.e. how many in group A purchased this item or did not and how many in group B purchased this item or did not) or [mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information) to determine which items provide the best distinction between groups. Both of these are implemented as [feature selection methods in the scikit-learn package](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html) in Python, and statsmodels of course [has the chi-square test](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_chisquare.html). (I guarantee all this can be done in R as well, although I use R less frequently and am therefore less familiar with all of the useful packages).

I would be aware of course that if using the chi-square test, be careful about how you interpret the p-value since you are of course performing many statistical tests (since you have thousands of items) and therefore if you decide to use a p-value cutoff as some measure of significance, if you do not perform a [multiple-test correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem) you have an increased chance of false positives. Also, if you are running cross-validation experiments when fitting your model, or if you assess your model on some validation or test set, you should perform the feature selection on the training data *only* to avoid over-estimating the performance of your model.

There are other ways to model this data, but I think these are probably the simplest given what I think you're trying to do.

**EDIT**: Another possible problem you may encounter involves highly correlated predictors. It is possible that some of the items you're tracking are highly correlated, in other words, people who buy tofu nearly always buy Impossible Burgers and almost never buy chicken, etc. There are a variety of ways you can deal with this.

One approach is to do [principal component analysis (PCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) if the data is number of items purchased (if it is instead one-hot encoded yes or no purchase, you can use [MCA instead](https://pypi.org/project/mca/), although it sounds like this is number of items purchased); there are a lot of tutorials on PCA online, it's implemented in scikit-learn and any other common statistical package. In a nutshell, PCA uses the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix as a new basis set for the data. The share of the variance explained by a given principal component (eigenvector) is its associated eigenvalue divided by the sum of all the eigenvalues; so, the principal components can be sorted by eigenvalue and we can use the new features associated with the *n* largest eigenvalues as input to our model while discarding the rest.

This will eliminate the multicollinearity problem (if present), but it's not ideal for your application, because now the odds ratios from logistic regression will be odds ratios *for the principal components*, each of which is a linear combination of the original items. This will somewhat complicate your analysis when you're trying to explain your insights to stakeholders. (Although maybe you can find a way to use this to give them an explanation that's sufficient for their needs).

So, I think what I would suggest instead as a place to start is doing feature selection, e.g. using mutual information, which should give you a greatly reduced number of features. At that point, you can check for correlations among those features (e.g. using the [Spearman's-r correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) if the data is the number of an item purchased by a customer). In any case where multiple items are very strongly correlated, you can keep one and eliminate the others as inputs to your logistic regression model. (This doesn't completely eliminate the possibility of multicollinearity but should significantly reduce the likelihood that it is a problem.) This way, when providing an interpretation to stakeholders, you can say "this is the odds ratio for tofu, we find that purchases of impossible meat are strongly correlated with tofu, i.e. customers who purchase the one nearly always purchase the other".

Also, elastic net regularization (combined L1 / L2) is likely to be especially helpful if you have multiple correlated features. L1 regularization alone will help with this but it will tend to keep one of the correlated features and drop the others, whereas elastic net can avoid this problem. Again some experiments on a subset of your data might be helpful here.

Comment: I would definitely cut down on the number of variables if you want to use a logistic model. when your variables are so high dimensional, it is almost certain that some of the variables basically tell the same story. Someone who buys more apples will likely also buy more bananas than the average customer. When variables tell the same story, it becomes statistically very difficult to tell their influence apart. The estimates for the variables effects become extremely shaky and non significant. 
I

Comment: How can you do a chisquare test comparing A and B for one item only ?

Comment: It is true that there may be multicollinearity; I will add some advice on how to deal with this if there are multiple highly correlated predictors.



It is straightforward to do a chi-squared test for feature selection, see scikit-learn's implementation for example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html The details depend on the data, but let's say for example you have category A and category B and # who purchased this item, yes or no; now you have a contingency table

Comment: PCA can be useful to re-express the data in an orthogonal basis, and you are correct to point out that doing so complicates interpretation. However, OP has stated interpretation is the explicit goal of the analysis, so PCA might not be the best choice. An alternative solution to rank-deficiency, prefect separation and multicollinearity in logistic regression is to use a penalized regression (e.g. [tag:ridge-regression], [tag:elastic-net]).

Comment: elastic-net is a good point, thanks, it is likely to work better than L1 regularization alone in that case, will add that as an edit.

Comment: linear discriminant analysis with shrinkage is another option (shrinkage probably necessary, if there is multicollinearity) or nearest shrunken centroids. Still, I tend to think logistic regression is the easiest to interpret, which is the main requirement here

Comment: Yes, I also suggested LDA before. The answer got deleted though ;-)
Thank you for clarifying what was meant with chisquare, and giving a link. According to the link, it is not a chi-square test for one item (that would be new to me).